# Cannot change from arabic to roman numerals in ConTeXt

Tags: page-numbering, context

I tried this MWE in ConTeXt standalone and live.contextgarden.net.

```
\definepapersize[main][width=6in,height=9in]
\setuppapersize[main]
\setupinterlinespace[line=14pt]
\setuplayout[backspace=0.8in,topspace=0.45in,footer=0mm,width=4.6in,header=0.450in,grid=yes,height=8in]
\setuppagenumbering[location=,alternative=doublesided,style=mediaeval]
\setupheader[text][state=empty,style=smallcaps]
\setupheadtext[content][header=empty,footer=empty]
\setupheadertexts[ ][{\word{\getmarking[chapter]}}\emspace{\pagenumber}][{\pagenumber}\emspace{test}][ ]
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={title,chapter,subject,section,subsection,subsubsection},alternative=c]
\setuplist[title][headnumber=no]
\setuplist[chapter][headnumber=no]
\setuphead[title][incrementnumber=yes, number=no]
\setuphead[title][style={\bf}]
\setuphead[chapter][style={\bf}]

%change page number from Arabic to Roman.  
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]
\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
\setcounter[userpage][1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\title{Daftar Isi}
\placecontent[criterium=all]
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodymatter
\startchapter[title=Test]
\input{knuth}
\stopchapter
\startchapter[title=Test2]
\input{knuth}
\stopchapter
\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

Both show roman numerals in ToC but Arabic numerals in the page header. How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem correctly. Does `\userpagenumber` instead of `\pagenumber` in the `\setupheadertexts` give you what you look for?

Comment: Yes. I thought it worked earlier with `\pagenumber` but I may not remember correctly. `\userpagenumber` solved it. Thanks.